# Filtering duplicates from pandas dataframe with preference based on additional column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to filter rows containing a duplicate in column X from a dataframe. However, if there are duplicates for a value in X, I would like to give preference to one of them based on the value of another column Y. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
print pd.__version__
x = pd.DataFrame([
    ['best', 'a', 'x'],
    ['worst', 'b', 'y'],
    ['best', 'c', 'x'],
    ['worst','d', 'y'],
    ['best','d', 'y'],
    ['worst','d', 'y'],
    ['best','d', 'z'],
    ['best','d', 'z'],
], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print x
x.drop_duplicates(cols='c', inplace=True)
print x

       a  b  c
0   best  a  x
1  worst  b  y
2   best  c  x
3  worst  d  y
4   best  d  y
5  worst  d  y
6   best  d  z
7   best  d  z

       a  b  c
0   best  a  x
1  worst  b  y
6   best  d  z
```

I would like to give precedence to the duplicate with column a equal to best. Which would give the result:

```
       a  b  c
0   best  a  x
4   best  d  y
6   best  d  z
```

Any idea what is the correct way to do this in pandas? Is there a more general way than just sorting the rows such that removing all but the first occurrence of the duplicate does what you want?

Comment: drop_duplicates drops keeps first row in frame unless take_last parameter is set to True.  You can always sort your dataframe by a then drop duplicates, but might not be the fastest option

Comment: See Phillip's solution. Mine *should* work, but there appears to be a bug. I've filed a GH issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7870

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a more straightforward way is to first sort the DataFrame, then drop duplicates keeping the first entry. This is pretty robust (here, 'a' was a string with two values but you could apply a function that makes an integer column from the string if there were more string values to sort).

```
x = x.sort_values(['a']).drop_duplicates(cols='c')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think using two `groupby` statements will get you what you want. With slightly modified input data:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([
    ['best', 'a', 'x'],
    ['worst', 'b', 'y'],
    ['best', 'c', 'x'],
    ['worst','d', 'y'],
    ['worst','d', 'y'],
    ['best','d', 'y'],
    ['best','d', 'z'],
    ['best','d', 'z'],
], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

x.groupby(by=['c']) \
 .filter(lambda g: g['a'] == 'best') \
 .groupby(by=['b'], as_index=False) \
 .first() \
 .sort(axis=1)  # the columns get out of order in the second groupby
```

Which returns:

```
   b     a  c
0  a  best  x
1  c  best  x
2  d  best  z
```

It's still not 100% clear where this needs to go with your ambiguous example input/output. But I think we're getting close.

Comment: When I run this, I get the error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). Also, would this solution work for the more general case where there are some duplicates that are both the same value for the 0/a column?

Comment: @dylkot It works on the example that you provided here. Can you expand the example to include the data that's throwing the error? Also, which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: version 0.12.0. I just copied your code into ipython so perhaps it is a version-based error. Upgrading now to check.

Comment: It was failing with version 0.12.0 but I just upgraded to 0.14.1 and it now works. However, the solution does not work if there are duplicates that are both 'best' or duplicates that are both 'worst'. I've edited the question to incorporate such examples.

Comment: Sorry, so just to clarify, I don't want there to be any duplicates in column c at the end of the filtering as in your solution. If one of the duplicates has column a=best and the other has column a=worse, I would like it to remove the one with a=worse. If a=best for both, I would like it to just keep the first row and filter subsequent ones and likewise if a=worst for both. I corrected my example so now it shouldn't have any errors. Sorry about that and thanks for your help!

Comment: Great, thanks so much. I am working on understanding groupby at the moment and so this is very helpful!

Comment: Turns out that the errors raised on version 0.12 *should* be raised on 0.14.1. The bug here is that `Grouby.filter` should apply to the entire subframe, not rows within the subframe.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of what @Paul H did (as he pointed out on the PyData mailing list there seems to be a weird bug in `GroupBy.filter` that is excluding `y` for some reason):

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
       a  b  c
0   best  a  x
1  worst  b  y
2   best  c  x
3   best  d  y
4  worst  d  y
5  worst  d  y
6   best  d  z

In [32]: besties = pd.concat(v[v.a == 'best'] for _, v in df.groupby('c'))

In [33]: besties
Out[33]:
      a  b  c
0  best  a  x
2  best  c  x
3  best  d  y
6  best  d  z

In [34]: res = besties.drop_duplicates(subset=['c'])

In [35]: res
Out[35]:
      a  b  c
0  best  a  x
3  best  d  y
6  best  d  z
```